# Is there a way to add a WSS4J interceptor for signing SOAP reqeust when using WS-SecurityPolicy approach?

Tags: java, cxf, ws-security

I am trying to create a `SOAP` client that follows `WS-SecurityPolicy`. The service requires `Timestamp`, `UsernameToken` and `Body` to be digitally signed in addition to encryption in the `SOAP` request.

The Keystore for signing the request is not available as a file (`jks`/`pfx`). I am using a USB based token from which I can load the Keystore programmatically. The USB token does not allow export to a `pfx` file.

Is there a way that I can override the Keystore used for signing using interceptors while using policy-based approach for WS-Security?

Spring config for WS-SecurityPolicy is similar to the following:

```java
<jaxws:client name="{http://cxf.apache.org}MyPortName"
      createdFromAPI="true">
      <jaxws:properties>
         <entry key="security.callback-handler"
             value="interop.client.KeystorePasswordCallback"/>
         <entry key="security.signature.properties"
             value="etc/client.properties"/>
         <entry key="security.encryption.properties"
             value="etc/service.properties"/>
         <entry key="security.encryption.username"
             value="servicekeyalias"/>
      </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:client>
```

Can this be configured along with an interceptor that will override the signature part? Instead of using the `security.signature.properties` in the above config I'd like to use an interceptor like below. Note: The code below uses libraries from `Spring-WS`. I am looking for analogous libs/classes from apache cxf that can be used for this case.

```java
@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() throws Exception {

    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();

    String secAction = String.join(" ", WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN,WSHandlerConstants.TIMESTAMP,WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE);

    // set security actions
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementActions(secAction);
    // sign the request
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername(config.getUsername());
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword(config.getPassword());
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementPasswordType(WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementUsernameTokenNonce(true);
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementUsernameTokenCreated(false);

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider", "org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin");

    Merlin crypto = (Merlin)CryptoFactory.getInstance(properties);
    crypto.setKeyStore(getKeyStore()); //This is my keystore fetched programmatically
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureKeyIdentifier("DirectReference");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureCrypto(crypto);

    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureParts("{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp;" +
    "{Element}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/ws-securitypolicy.xsd}UsernameToken;" +
    "{Element}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body");

    return securityInterceptor;
}
```

I have tried using `Spring-WS`to implement the soap client using `Wss4jSecurityInterceptor` shown above. With that, the spring config shown first is not needed.

```java
CommVerRequest request = new CommVerRequest();

            prepareRequest(pan, request);

            SOAPClient client = soapClientConfig.getSoapClient();
            CommVerResponse callResponse = client.call(request);

            /*CommVerResponse callResponse = port.verifyDetails(request);*/


            validationResponse = prepareResponse(callResponse);
```

```java
@Bean
    public SOAPClient getSoapClient() throws Exception {
        SOAPClient soapClient = new SOAPClient();
        soapClient.setDefaultUri("https://foo.bar/CommVerService");
        ClientInterceptor[] interceptors = new ClientInterceptor[]{securityInterceptor()};
        soapClient.setInterceptors(interceptors);

        soapClient.setMarshaller(marshaller());
        soapClient.setUnmarshaller(marshaller());

        return soapClient;
    }
```

```java
@Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("flatStub");
        return marshaller;
    }
```

However while calling the web service I get this error.

```java
WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.

org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.internalInsertBefore(ParentNode.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.insertBefore(ParentNode.java:288) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(NodeImpl.java:237) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.util.WSSecurityUtil.prependChildElement(WSSecurityUtil.java:314) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.util.WSSecurityUtil.findWsseSecurityHeaderBlock(WSSecurityUtil.java:435) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecHeader.insertSecurityHeader(WSSecHeader.java:165) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.doSenderAction(WSHandler.java:117) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jHandler.doSenderAction(Wss4jHandler.java:63) ~[spring-ws-security-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.secureMessage(Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.java:574) ~[spring-ws-security-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.handleRequest(AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.java:210) ~[spring-ws-security-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:597) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:383) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:373) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by this this blog post below, we pushed the version up to Spring 2.1.10.RELEASE that is coming with Spring WS Security 3.0.8.RELEASE and subsequently `org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-dom:jar:2.2.3:compile` to fix the error. You could override just the WSS4J dependency up, but I prefered bumping the entire suite.

https://better-coding.com/solved-org-w3c-dom-domexception-wrong_document_err/

I would check my dependency tree to see you have the same problem:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```